# Listview adapter with gridview inside linearlayout showing items below eachother instead of in two columns

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a ListView custom adapter using a gridview inside a linear layout to display user profiles.

My XML design view shows them correctly. However, when I run the app, it's showing each item below each other instead of spread over 2 columns.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxeoc.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rimage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/thumb_default_icon_female" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rnick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/nick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rcity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/city" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Showing
[List Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzN5B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current list items logic is something like this:

```
Item 1--> LinearLayout
        -->GridView
        -->ImageView
        -->TextView
        -->TextView

Item 2--> LinearLayout
        -->GridView
        -->ImageView
        -->TextView
        -->TextView
```

So in actual case, your items are LinearLayouts taking up the whole width of the device's screen.

Instead of a ListView, you should use a GridView as your items' container and you should implement your customAdapter to use LinearLayout items:

Your GridView in your Activity's layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Your items' layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rimage"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/thumb_default_icon_female" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rnick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="@string/nick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rcity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="@string/city" />
```

and set your adapter to your GridView directly. Make sure your adapter extends BaseAdapter (not ListAdapter);

```
yourGridView.setAdapter(yourCustomAdapter);
```

All in all, a better approach would be to use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Here is a simple tutorial](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview-grid-layout-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now I'm getting my items next to eachother (as required) but the gridview is not scrollable like my listview was. Any idea on how to fix this? (I'm truly new to Android Studio). I've changed the setadapter to a gridview.

Comment: Glad it helped! In your activity xml, change your GridView's height from match_parent to android:layout_height="wrap_content". I've also edited my answer. Please also accept my answer if this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First of you should not be using a GridView but instead a **RecyclerView** since it has replaced the functionality of the old **ListView** and **GridView**.

Than to achieve what you want you need to create a **GridLayoutManager** with span count 2.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 gridLayoutManagerVertical =
            new GridLayoutManager(this,
                    2, //The number of Columns in the grid
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Nested LinearLayout instead of gridLayout, also you i think you forgot to put view inside the gridLayout, since they are outside the gridLayout and child of LinearLayout thats why they are displaying one below another. try the code below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rimage"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/thumb_default_icon_female" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rnick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="@string/nick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rcity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="@string/city" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```